# How to get input from text entry after destroying window

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

im new to this site (and Python) and this is my first post so im sorry if something is not clear. Basically, im trying to write a code that simulates a lottery. For this, i use tkinter and text-entry to fill in numbers. The problem appears when i destroy the input-window, where the guessed numbers are not saved. My question is, how do i destroy my window and get the input from the text-entry?

I've tried using IntVar without success, not sure if i understood it correctly.

```py
from tkinter import*
import random

Part1 = list(range(1,51))
Part2 = list(range(1,11))

Numbers = [0]*7

for n in range (5):
    Number = random.choice(Part1)

    Position = Part1.index(Number)
    del Part1[Position]

    Numbers[n] = Number


for i in range (2):
    Number = random.choice(Part2)

    Position = Part2.index(Number)
    del Part2[Position]

    Numbers[5+i] = Number

print (Numbers)


def master1_quit():
    master1.destroy()   

# def window():

master1 = Tk()

Label(master1, text="Guess numbers:").grid(row=0)

e1 = Text(master1, width=2, height=1)
e2 = Text(master1, width=2, height=1)
e3 = Text(master1, width=2, height=1)
e4 = Text(master1, width=2, height=1)
e5 = Text(master1, width=2, height=1)
e6 = Text(master1, width=2, height=1)
e7 = Text(master1, width=2, height=1)


e1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
e2.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)
e3.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5)
e4.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=5)
e5.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=5)
e6.grid(row=0, column=7, padx=5)
e7.grid(row=0, column=8, padx=5)

master1.grid_columnconfigure(6, minsize=20) # Creates an empty column (nr. 6) with width 20

# Save guessed numbers
Guess = [e1.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e2.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e3.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e4.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e5.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e6.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e7.get(1.0, "end-1c")]

Button(master1, text='OK', command=master1_quit).grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W, pady=5)



master1.mainloop()


# window()
```

Basically i want the variable "Guess" to be saved after the window is destroyed because i want to use it later.

Extra question: 
Is it possible to write "def window()" and call the window with "window()" later in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for the clear question.

If you change the `master1_quit` function to update the global variable `Guess` as the window exits, `Guess` will show the final state of the 7 Text widgets, example below.  In your code `Guess` is filled from the 7 Text widgets as the UI is created.  At that point all the Text fields are empty.

```
def master1_quit():
    global Guess
    Guess = [e1.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e2.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e3.get(1.0, "end-1c"),
             e4.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e5.get(1.0, "end-1c"), e6.get(1.0, "end-1c"),
             e7.get(1.0, "end-1c")]
    master1.destroy()
```

For such simple data you may find Entry widgets easier than Text widgets.  You can use e1.get() to recover the text in an Entry widget, with no parameters to worry about.